# Is affirmation of the consequent always invalid?

Tags: logic, propositional-logic

Examples that I've seen usually go something like

"If the lamp is off, then the room is dark. The room is dark, therefore the lamp must be off."

However, what about the following example

"If it is January 1st, then it is my birthday. It is my birthday, therefore it must be January 1st."

This statement affirms the consequent, yet it is a valid.

Comment: The reason your second example is valid is because it is a biconditional. It is your birthday if and only if it is January 1st. With biconditionals, affirming the consequent and denying the antecedent are valid forms.

Comment: First, statements cannot be valid or invalid, they can be true or false, what can be be valid or invalid are inferences. And second, the inference about birthdays has a hidden premise folded into the meaning of "birthday" (one and only one day of the year is a birthday). So your inference does not affirm the consequent, it only looks like that superficially when the hidden premise and reasoning associated with it are omitted. Replace "birthday" with "happy day" and you'll see that it is invalid.

Comment: There's another place in which affirming the consequent can work - probabilistic reasoning. If you apply Bayes Theorem to most situations, affirming the consequent increases the probability of the antecedent most of the time, I'm pretty sure, maybe all the time?

Answer (score 0):

Validity is a notion such that if it is even violated once, then it is necessarily violated. That is, an argument is valid iff the premises guarantee the conclusion by the form of the argument alone. So, even if you could state an instance of affirming the consequent that preserves truth, the reason that it preserves truth is different from the argument form used. For your example, you’re implicitly assuming “it is January 1st iff it is my birthday,” so you’re really using regular Modus Ponens/affirming the antecedent.

Another way of thinking of it is that since a contradiction (P&~P) can never be true, it must be always invalid to infer it, right? Wrong! If you have an inconsistent set of formulas *A*, then from *A* you may validly infer (P&~P). This is just an example to clear up that there is no such thing as a contingently valid argument within the constraints of a specific logic.